# Why can't I save any models to PostgreSQL database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

All of a sudden, I cannot save any models in my PostgreSQL database in Rails. Retrieving data works fine.

```
m = Model.find(1)
m.save
=> false
```

When I switched to another database, it is fine. There is no entry in the Rails log.

What could cause this behavior? Is the database corrupt? Is the disk dying? I tried rebooting but that did not help.

How can you check the integrity of the database (I have pgAdmin III installed)? Do I need to do some maintenance? How to figure out what the problem is?

Working in Ubuntu 11.04, Rails 3.0.7 and PostgreSQL 8.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added any validations since that object was created? Try this:

```
> m = Model.find(1)
> m.valid?
> m.errors.full_messages
```

If something was wrong with your PostgreSQL database you'd probably be seeing exceptions and read errors.

Comment: This helped me find the answer. As usual, it was ***programmer*** error. Validations I added a long time ago were failing, but this was the first time I tried to save the object.

Comment: @BSeven: You've found a good argument for having your validations inside the database (as CHECK constraints and FKs) even though Rails doesn't understand them; you'd want them in your models as well of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try a

```
m.save!
```

and it should give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the database corrupt? Is the disk dying?

If it is, showing three lines of Ruby code isn't going to help. If you want to know whether your database is working, look at the database. If PgAdmin works, then the db is fine. You might want to turn on query logging in the db then, to see what query (if anything) Rails is sending.